# Merge with a preferred source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using SSIS 2008 R2 for a few weeks now and I'm stuck at this moment.

I need to merge two tables from two different SQL Servers into a new table.

This is what I try to achieve:

**Table 1**:

```
Name     Price  Quantity
------------------------
Item 1   23      5
Item 2   50      2
Item 3   30     10
```

**Table 2**:

```
ID   Name     Price   Quantity
------------------------------
101  Item 1     60       7
203  Item 3     80      15
```

**Result**:

```
ID    Name     Price   Quantity
-------------------------------------
101   Item 1    60       7
NULL  Item 2    50       2
203   Item 3    80      15
```

I've tried to use merge but that duplicates Item 1 and Item 3.

I'm trying to create it within Development Studio so there is no real code that I can show.
[This is what I've created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMakq.jpg)

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Add the code you wrote that causes duplicates, so we can help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T2.ID, T1.Name,Price=case when isnull(T1.Price,0)>isnull(T2.Price,0) then 
isnull(T1.Price,0) else isnull(T2.Price,0) end, 
Quantity=case when isnull(T1.Quantity,0)>isnull(T2.Quantity,0)  
then isnull(T1.Quantity,0) else isnull(T2.Quantity,0) end
 from Table1 T1
left outer join Table2 T2 on T1.Name=T2.Name
```

Comment: If you want to query among table of other server then link this server in your server..

Comment: [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]